Stacktraces : how to identify the script (when using dynamic scripts)?
Let's say we have 2 dynamic scripts, generated locally, e.g.:
const scripts = [
    "console.log(new Error().stack)",
    "console.log(new Error().stack)"
];

We can run them in the webpage in different ways:
for(let i = 0; i < scripts.length; ++i) {
     (new Function(scripts[i]))();
     //or
     let script = document.createElement("script");
     script.textContent = scripts[i];
     document.body.append(script);
}

In Firefox, the stacks will be identical:

new Function(): anonymous@....html line ... > Function:3:12
body.append() : @....html line ... > injectedScript:1:12

Therefore, if e.g. an exception is thrown in one of my dynamic script, I won't be able to tell, from the stack, which one raised it.
Is there a way to inject my dynamic scripts in a way that will give me an indication, in the stack, of which script raised it ?
I found a kind of dirty hack, consisting of building another Function with additional lines:
new Function(`
     ${"".padEnd(scriptID, "\n")}
     new Function("${script}");
`)


In Firefox, this makes the stack looks like:
... > Function line ${offset+scriptID} > Function:3:13

But this is quite a dirty hack. Is there a better way to do so ?

This is part of the reason why dynamically injecting scripts is very far from an ideal solution. What exactly are you trying to achieve - as I'm certain there is a more effective way to do it.

@RoryMcCrossan I generate JS code from Python code, in order to then execute it in the Browser.
My goal is to produce a PoC of "JS stacktrace -> Python stacktrace" conversion that maybe could be used in Brython instead of doing the Python stack by hand that cause some issues.
I also use it in my pet project, trying to reimplement Brython but with different design choices.

For reference, if I forget to update, it seems the //# sourceURL directive could do the trick. I'll have to test it tomorrow.
